# Don't export multiple sheet with excel on Jasper Server 5.6.1

Tags: jasperserver

Now, I'm using IReport 5.6.0 and Jasper Server 5.6.1 and face a issue with them.
I use IReport to design a form and deploy it to Jasper Server. I want to use Jasper Server to export excel report with multiple sheet (one page per sheet).
When I export excel report with IReport, I have a multiple sheet excel but with Jasper Server, I don't.
I have set up `property name="onePagePerSheet" value="true"` in `applicationContext.xml` file
and put line property 
`name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet" value="true"` in .jrxml file.

Finally, I try to export with sample report **Sales By Month** Report in sample folder of Jasper Server also don't export multiple sheet. 
What is my mistake?

Comment: Does it export single sheet?

Comment: Yes, It export all page in sheet.